# Console Application Process Getting Called Twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application, .net-4.6

I'm calling a console application from a Web Form which sends out an email blast. In the finally block of the console code, a confirmation email is sent with a count of successful emails.

During runtime, two confirmation mails are being generated instead of one; the first one always has 0 email count, and the second one has the actual count.

Here is the calling code in the Web Form:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

string arguments = String.Format(@"""{0}"" ""{1}""", 
    message.Subject.Replace(@"""", @""""""), 
    message.Body.Replace(@"""", @""""""));
info.FileName = MAILER_FILEPATH;

Process process = Process.Start(info.FileName, arguments);
Process.Start(info);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, of course it's starting twice; you're calling `Process.Start` twice.

Comment: So I don't need the ProcessStartInfo class at all here?

Comment: ProcessStartInfo is fine; just either choose that or the other method; but you're mixing the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're calling `Process.Start` twice; once with the `info` object (but without arguments), and the next with the filename and arguments overload.

You have two methods for starting a process shown; you should pick one and stick with it:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

string arguments = String.Format(@"""{0}"" ""{1}""", 
    message.Subject.Replace(@"""", @""""""), 
    message.Body.Replace(@"""", @""""""));
info.FileName = MAILER_FILEPATH;
info.Arguments = arguments;

Process.Start(info);
```

`ProcessStartInfo` includes a property called `Arguments` that you can add the arguments to; and there's an overload of `Process.Start` that just takes a `ProcessStartInfo` object.  That's the method I describe above.

Comment: Thanks George, that fixed it.